# Why the component.ts cannot assign to the interface's variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, single-page-application

I am trying to modify Tour of Heroes samples.

The service is returning a name from the Hero interface as an observable and I am subscribing to it in the component.

service

```
getHeroesByName(HeroName: string=''): Observable<string>
  {
       
        this.messageService.add(HeroName + "is feteched.");
        HEROES[0].name= HEROES.find(h => h.name == HeroName)?.name as string;

        return of(HEROES[0].name);
  }
```

component

```
 export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
    
       //SelectedHero?= HEROES;
       Heroes: Hero[]= [];
       HeroNameReturned: Hero[]= [];
    
      selectedName= "";
      selectedHero?: Hero;
      ReturnedHero?: Hero;
    
      constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {
    
       }
    
      //  getHeroes(): void
      //  {
      //    //this.Heroes= this.heroService.getHeroes();
      //    this.heroService.getHeroes("Fazal Fasil").subscribe(heroes => this.Heroes = heroes);
      //  }
    
       getHeroesByName(selectedName: string): void
       {
         //this.Heroes= this.heroService.getHeroes();
         this.heroService.getHeroesByName(selectedName).subscribe(heroname => this.HeroNameReturned[0].name = heroname);
         this.ReturnedHero.name=  this.HeroNameReturned[0].name;
         this.Heroes.push(this.ReturnedHero);
         
         console.log(this.Heroes.length)
        
       }
```

but

```
 this.ReturnedHero.name=  this.HeroNameReturned[0].name;
```

is not getting assigned to `this.ReturnedHero.name`.

Error:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of asynchrony.

Here you say, that `ReturnedHero` can be undefined.

```
ReturnedHero?: Hero;
```

So in order to make sure that `ReturnedHero` has definitely a value, you have to put the assignment inside the subscription.

```
getHeroesByName(selectedName: string): void {            
    this.heroService.getHeroesByName(selectedName).subscribe(
        heroname => {
            this.HeroNameReturned[0].name = heroname;
            this.ReturnedHero.name = this.HeroNameReturned[0].name;
            this.Heroes.push(this.ReturnedHero);
            console.log(this.Heroes.length);
       }
    );
}
```

If you leave it outside, the assignment happens long before the subscription returns a value and at this point in time `ReturnedHero` is still undefined.

Comment: hi thanks. but same error : Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Comment: Oh, now I see. Your problem is, that you do not have a Hero-Object at all. It is and will stay undefined. And thus you cannot put something in the name-property. So you have to find a way to make `ReturnedHero` either a valid Hero-object before or you let `getHeroesByName()` return a list of Hero-Objects and not only a list of Hero-Names.